# What is the best way to send a reboot (shutdown) command to a Windows server?

Tags: system-administration, windows-server-2019

I'm basically trying to **avoid** forwarding ports for remote desktop. 
Is there a reliable and secure way to send a reboot command to a Windows server over the internet?

The CMD and PowerShell commands seem promising but I have no clue which ports or services they use.

SQL Server 2019 is installed on the server and it seems to have some server management functionality but I can't figure out how to use it.

I heard about WMI but I don't think I understand it well enough to use it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it a regularly scheduled reboot, where there should be no need to send a command at all?

Comment: @DaveS no, this is intermittent and when needed